# Prolog - print the sum of the EVEN numbers from 1 to 10

Tags: prolog

I am trying to print all the even numbers from 1 to 10 using Prolog, and here is what I have tried:

```
printn(10,0):- write(10),!.
printn(X,Sum):- 
    ( X mod 2 =:= 0 -> Sum is X+Sum, Next is X+1, nl, printn(Next);
      Next is X+1, printn(Next) ).
```

but it returns false.

Comment: What is the error you get? Anyway, if you don't want to print all numbers, you shouldn't have a `printn` call in both branches!

Comment: it prints false

Comment: You cannot write like 'Sum is X+Sum'  in prolog. Prolog's variable cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create the list with the numbers from the beginning, it is better to examine numbers once:

```
print(X,Y):-print_even(X,Y,0).

print_even(X, X, Sum):- 
    (   X mod 2 =:= 0 -> Sum1 is X+Sum; 
        Sum1 = Sum
    ), print(Sum1).
print_even(X, Y, Sum):- 
    X<Y, Next is X+1,
    (   X mod 2 =:= 0 -> Sum1 is X+Sum, print_even(Next, Y, Sum1); 
        print_even(Next, Y, Sum)
    ).
```

Keep in mind that in Prolog `Sum is Sum+1` always fails you need to use a new variable e.g `Sum1`.

Example:

```
?- print(1,10).
30
true ;
false.
```

Comment: doesn't work ,, it prints the following error uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,p/1),print_even/3)

Comment: Hmm weird... seems you haven't loaded print_even/3, make sure you have copy pasted the above code in a file.pl and consult it again and tell me...

Answer (score 2):

The most useful way of obtaining Prolog output is to capture the solution in a variable, either individually through backtracking, or in a list. The idea of "printing", which carries over from using other languages allows for formatting, etc, but is not considered the best way to express a solution.

In Prolog, you want to express your problem as a relation. For example, we might say, `even_with_max(X, Max)` is true (or succeeds) if `X` is an even number less than or equal to `Max`. In Prolog, when reasoning with integers, the CLP(FD) library is what you want to use.

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

even_up_to(X, Max) :-
    X in 1..Max,
    X mod 2 #= 0,   % EDIT: as suggested by Taku
    label([X]).
```

This will yield:

```
3 ?- even_up_to(X, 10).
X = 2 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 8 ;
X = 10.
```

If you then want to collect into a list, you can use: `findall(X, even_up_to(X), Evens).`

Comment: I think writing 'X mod 2 #= 0' constraint before 'label' is better.

Comment: @TakuKoyahata I agree. I didn't have a chance to look up `mod` to see if it was supported by CLP(FD).

Comment: Before Carlo gets here, `aggregate(sum(E), (between(1,10,E), E mod 2 =:= 0), Sum).`

Comment: @DanielLyons :) you should add that as another answer choice.

Answer (score 1):

What error do you have? Here is my solution:

1. Create list [1...10]
2. Filter it, excluding odd numbers
3. Sum elements of the list

Code:

```
sumList([], 0).
sumList([Head|Tail], Sum) :-
   sumList(Tail, Rest),
   Sum is Head + Rest.

isOdd(X) :-
    not((X mod 2) =:= 0).

sumOfEvenNums(A, B, Out) :- 
    numlist(A, B, Numbers),
    exclude(isOdd, Numbers, Even_numbers),
    sumList(Even_numbers, Out).
```

Now you can call `sumOfEvenNums(1, 10, N)`

Comment: is there is a way to solve this problem without using the list ??

Answer (score 1):

In ECLiPSe, you can write with iterator:

```
sum_even(Sum):-
( for(I,1,10),fromto(0,In,Out,Sum)
    do
  (I mod 2 =:= 0 -> Out is In + I;Out is In)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

With [library(aggregate)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate):

```
evens_upto(Sum) :-
  aggregate(sum(E), (between(1, 10, E), E mod 2 =:= 0), Sum).
```

Thanks to @CapelliC for the inspiration.